# ExtJs: defaultFocus does not place the focus on form textfield

Tags: extjs

See this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36vh.
Even though the defaultFocus is set properly by referencing the component via #fldxyz, the component doesn't get the focus.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'myapp',

    // autoCreateViewport is deprecated
    mainView: 'myapp.MyPanel',

    launch : function() {
    }
});

Ext.define('myapp.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',          // does not work
//    extend: 'MyPanel',                // works

    layout: 'fit',
    //defaultFocus: '[reference=fld]',
    //defaultFocus: 'textfield:first',
    defaultFocus: '#fldxyz',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'anchor',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            value: 'Indigo',
            id: 'fldxyz',
            //reference: 'fld',
            selectOnFocus: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last',
            value: 'Montoya'
        }]
    }]
});
```

I tested it with 6.6.0 and 7.2.0.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [doc of defaultFocus](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#cfg-defaultFocus) is following: *Specifies a child Component to receive focus when this Container's method-focus method is called.*
You are not calling the focus() method and it is not focused. I have added it in the 'afterrender' listener event.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'myapp',
    mainView: 'myapp.MyPanel'
});

Ext.define('myapp.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: "My Form Panel",
    layout: 'fit',
    defaultFocus: '#fldxyz',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'anchor',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            value: 'Indigo',
            id: 'fldxyz',
            selectOnFocus: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last',
            value: 'Montoya'
        }]
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(formPanel) {
            formPanel.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you.